# How to link to class methods in doxygen html

Tags: doxygen

I've got a setup where I use doxygen to describe a set on unit tests (I use QtTest to run the tests). The output from the tests are parsed by a little Python snippet that produces a nice and tidy report. Now, I'd love to link from the report to each test case, i.e. private slot member method, in the doxygen material. However, the anchors defined by doxygen looks like this:

```
<a class="anchor" id="a2a0e066d4dad8e0dff6c9231bf65fd65"></a>
<!-- doxytag: member="PRadioTunerTst::scanFM" ref="a2a0e066d4dad8e0dff6c9231bf65fd65" args="()" -->
```

Sure, I could parse the doxygen html and match all method to the reference key, but I'd much rather have readable links. I do not overload any unit test case methods, so having them enumerated would not be an issue - I'd simply be able to pick the first and only. I'd even be happy to calculate the id hash myself. I just need to know how to.

So, basically, the questions is:

- Does anyone know how to tune doxygen
  to generate readable anchors
- if not, how do I calculate the hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to reconstruct the hash (which is a md5 checksum over the method's definition as parsed by doxygen, see MemberDef::setAnchor() in the code). I would suggest to let doxygen generate a tag file (GENERATE_TAGFILE) and then parse that. The tag file is a simple XML file which has both the name and the anchor for each member.

Comment: I'm trying to link to doxygen-generated html files from a separate LaTeX-generated PDF. I don't want my LaTeX file to have to parse an XML file every time it compiles. This seems like overengineering here. Is there a reason doxy can't output human readable anchors?

Comment: Let me clarify. I'd like to be able to refer to the top of the set of overridden class methods easily. If there's a getFoo(int) getFoo(float) etc declared in my class, what would be nice is if a #getFoo anchor would simply point at the first one's description in the HTML.

If the tagfile is not ordered in the same order the methods are laid out on the html page, then it doesn't solve my problem. I wouldn't know which anchor points to the first override as it appears in the html.

Comment: Anchors may only contain ascii characters and underscores and are not case sensitive, so they cannot be used for readable names (ref http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1)

Comment: I understand that if getFoo and getfoo are declared in the same class, then a #getFoo anchor would be less useful. Nevertheless, doxygen orders the methods alphabetically, so there would be a location in the HTML file where get[Ff]oo begins and ends. If there was an anchor that allowed me to direct my users to the beginning of that section, that would work just as well for my purposes. Semantically, you would expect that all the methods named getFoo in some form or another relate to each other, so there should be a way to refer to them as a group.

Comment: Sorting of methods is a configuration option (SORT_MEMBER_DOCS), so one cannot rely on that. So your request is *very* specific, and would not work reliably in general.

Comment: How do you suggest I accomplish what I set out to do? I feel like my request is not as specific as you think, seeing as though the original poster of this question is attempting to do the same thing.

Will I have to make use of an XML parser in my LaTeX file? Should I reference the raw hash anchors that doxygen outputs? What if a developer changes a parameter type and inadvertently changes the hash, breaking my anchor link?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed link targets, in my case for rst docs to point at breathe/doxygen-created html.  Here's what I did:

To better understand how doxygen creates anchors, I recompiled doxygen, with this at the end of setAnchor():

`printf("memAnchor=%s sigStr=%s\n", memAnchor.data(), sigStr.data());`

, which creates output like:

```
memAnchor=const int SomeNamespace::GetStateGetState(SomeNamespace::State *state) sigStr=f2c41a8a6a152602c92fefb80bd0862a
```

I already had my function signatures, so I created strings similar to memAnchor above and piped it through md5sum to get the hash, then appended it to the string which is common to all anchors.  In my rst doc, I then put definitions like:

```
.. _GetState: `project0class_SomeNamespace_1f2c41a8a6a152602c92fefb80bd0862a`_
```

Not sure on the first question about readable anchors.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly needs to be done. Can you rephrase the answer in a more succinct manner?